# Rails5 integration test assert_equal with flash messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing

In Rails 5,2 a very simple system test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class AdminSignsInTest < ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase
  driven_by :selenium, using: :firefox

  test 'admin can sign in' do
    @user = users(:admin)
    visit new_user_session_path
    fill_in 'user_username', with: @user.username
    fill_in 'user_password', with: @user.encrypted_password
    click_button I18n.t("devise.login")
    assert_equal I18n.t('devise.failure.invalid'), flash[:alert] 
  end
end
```

returns the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `flash' for nil:NilClass
```

According to Rails documentation http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-flash-notices this syntax should work, for example:

```
assert_equal 'Article was successfully created.', flash[:notice]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in the `@response` or `response` object must have the alert message. You can try that.

Comment: It seems that `assert_equal` with `flash` is not supported by **ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase** class, but **ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest**